# Toggle div containers based on navigation link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So, i have a simple navigation with 3 items:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Open first</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Open second</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Open third</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This one doesnt open anything</a></li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

Above it, i have a 3 div's, one for each menu link.

```
<div id="content-1" style="background:red">Lorem</div>
<div id="content-2" style="background:blue">Lorem</div>
<div id="content-3" style="background:yellow">Lorem</div>
```

I am trying to get a toggle effect on them, so when user clicks on link, div gets pushed from the top, while moving the menu down.
Once the div is opened and the user clicks on another link, it shouldnt go up, it should only display the content of another div.

I am a jQuery newbie and no matter what i tried, i couldnt make it work...

Fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/jh2j50df/

Comment: your fiddle doesn't "try" anything, please show what jquery attempt you have made

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/jh2j50df/3/

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div id="content-1" style="background:red">Lorem</div>
<div id="content-2" style="background:blue">Lorem</div>
<div id="content-3" style="background:yellow">Lorem</div>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a id="content-1link" href="#">Open first</a></li>
        <li><a id="content-2link" href="#">Open second</a></li>
        <li><a id="content-3link" href="#">Open third</a></li>
        <li><a id="content-4link" href="#">This one doesnt open anything</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#content-1link").click(function () {
        if ($("#content-1").height() == 20) {
            $("#content-1").animate({
                height: "200px"
            });
        } else {
            $("#content-1").animate({
               height: "20px"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Skaadel/jh2j50df/8/

If i understood the question right, it is something like this you are looking for. The code itself is not that good, you could probably make it with 1 function instead of 4, but I'm not that good at JQuery myself.

Hope this helps!

Remember to add the JQuery framework when you add it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<div id="content-1" style="background:red">Lorem</div>
<div id="content-2" style="background:blue">Lorem</div>
<div id="content-3" style="background:yellow">Lorem</div>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#content-1, #content-2, #content-3').hide();
   $('a').on('click',function(){
       var container = $(this).data('container');
       if ($(container).css('display') == 'none') {
          $('#content-1, #content-2, #content-3').hide();
       }
       $(container).toggle();
     })
   })
</script>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jh2j50df/9/

Comment: this one is great! but is it possible to also close the div if it is opened by clicking on the link?